# How to solve "open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to date.exe.stackdump" error?

Tags: git, windows-7, gnu-make, msysgit, msys

Can someone help me on this problem?

I have been using GNU make on Windows 7 to build c++ applications. The source control app is Git. Everything was working fine until recently. Whenever I ran "make *target_name*", I got the errors below:

```
Building with DISTROOT = /c/f1/f1a/f1aa
      0 [main] date 20856 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to date.exe.stackdump
      0 [main] date 11964 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to date.exe.stackdump
      0 [main] date 20588 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to date.exe.stackdump
      0 [main] date 10768 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to date.exe.stackdump
      0 [main] gawk 17820 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to gawk.exe.stackdump
      0 [main] gawk 6672 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to gawk.exe.stackdump
      0 [main] gawk 18680 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to gawk.exe.stackdump
      0 [main] gawk 19040 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to gawk.exe.stackdump
      0 [main] gawk 20904 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to gawk.exe.stackdump
--------------------------------------------------------------------  
Git repository detected... git version 1.9.4.msysgit.1
--------------------------------------------------------------------
      0 [main] gawk 15636 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to gawk.exe.stackdump
      0 [main] gawk 412 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to gawk.exe.stackdump Checking dependencies Creating temporary path

./bld/win7-x64-vc12-debug/tmp
      0 [main] mkdir 19036 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to mkdir.exe.stackdump make: *** [mktmppath] Error 5
```

I can run date.exe without an issue. So I don't understand what is wrong here.

I use MINGW32_NT-6.1, GNU Make 3.81. Couldn't find a solution on SO or the internet. Have anyone seen this issue before? Let me if more information is needed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by version conflicts of msys commands. I have 2 'msys' paths in my local environment variable PATH, one is for 1.0.17, the other is for 1.8.4. I use make.exe from 1.0.17 and I use git.exe is from 1.8.4. After I moved the path of msys 1.8.4 after the path of msys 1.0.17 in PATH value, the problem was solved.